# ERROR: invalid redefinition of constant FXQuote in Julia

Tags: julia

I am new in Julia. I didn't redifining types. And here is the error message:

ERROR: invalid redefinition of constant FXQuote
Stacktrace:
[1] top-level scope
@ /home/ex002.jl:5

Here is the code.

```
using HTTP
using JSON


mutable struct FXQuote
    AskPrice::String
    BidPrice::String
    Currency::String
end

function Retrive_WebData(_url)
    _headers = Dict("User-Agent" => "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36")
    _content = String(HTTP.get(_url, _headers).body)
    _data = JSON.parse(_content)["records"]
    return _data
end

_url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/"
_data = Retrive_WebData(_url)

_dict_Data = Dict()
for i in _data
    _key = i["ccyPair"]
    _fxquote = FXQuote(i["askPrc"], i["bidPrc"], i["ccyPair"])
    _dict_Data[_key] = _fxquote
end

println(_dict_Data["USD/CNY"].BidPrice)
```

The version of Julia is 1.8.5.
How do I solve this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just restart your Julia session and run the code again.
To me, the root of the problem can be modifying the struct definition after the first run. Example:

```
julia> mutable struct FXQuote
           AskPrice::String
           BidPrice::String
           Currency::String
       end

julia> struct FXQuote
           AskPrice::String
           BidPrice::String
           Currency::String
       end
ERROR: invalid redefinition of constant FXQuote
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope
   @ REPL[3]:1
```

I modified the `FXQuote` struct in the second run into an immutable struct, and the expected error occurred. In the following example, I'll alter the struct in the second run by changing the type of the `Currency` param:

```
julia> mutable struct FXQuote
           AskPrice::String
           BidPrice::String
           Currency::String
       end

julia> mutable struct FXQuote
           AskPrice::String
           BidPrice::String
           Currency::Int64
       end
ERROR: invalid redefinition of type FXQuote
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope
   @ REPL[2]:1
```

As you can see, modification causes the error.

Comment: Just restart the Julia session and the code run smoothly. Thanks.